# Using .Find won't continue, stays on same paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a script that looks for some text, inputted by the user.  The idea is to look through a document for this text, and when it's found, select the paragraph and ask the user if they want to add this paragraph to an Index.

For some reason, I can't get the script to move past the first selected paragraph.  When I run it, and click "Yes" in the UserForm (equivalent of `myForm.Tag = 2`), it adds to the index, but then when the `.Find` looks for the next instance of the text, it selects the paragraph I just had highlighted. ...it doesn't continue.

Here's the code:

```
Sub find_Definitions()
Dim defText As String, findText$
Dim oRng    As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range
Dim myForm As frmAddDefinition
Set myForm = New frmAddDefinition

Dim addDefinition$, expandParagraph&
' expandParagraph = 1

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
findText = InputBox("What text would you like to search for?")

With oRng.Find
    .Text = findText
    While .Execute

    Set rng = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range
        rng.Select
        defText = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range
        myForm.Show
        Select Case myForm.Tag
            Case 0 ' Expand the paragraph selection

                Do While CLng(expandParagraph) < 1
                    expandParagraph = InputBox("How many paragraphs to extend selection?")
                    If expandParagraph = 0 Then Exit Do
                Loop

                    rng.MoveEnd unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=expandParagraph
                    rng.Select
                    defText = rng

                ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=rng, entry:=defText, entryautotext:=defText
            Case 1 ' No, do not add to the index
                ' do nothing
            Case 2 ' Yes, add to index
                ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=rng, entry:=defText, entryautotext:=defText
            Case 3 ' Cancel, exit the sub
                MsgBox ("Exiting macro")
                GoTo lbl_Exit
        End Select
    Wend
End With

lbl_Exit:
Unload myForm
Set myForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

(FWIW, I'm pretty new to Word VBA, but very familiar with Excel VBA).  Thanks for any ideas.

Note if I click "No" (equivalent of `myForm.Tag = 1`), then it **does** move on to the next instance.  Hmm.

Comment: Try adding rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd before the "Case 1" line. Explanation: When you use Find, it executes on the given Range or Selection. If it's successful, that Range/Selection changes to include the "found" term. In this case, you in addition change the assignment again (expanding to include the paragraph). When your code loops the current assignment to "Range" is used. So you need to reset the Range. To be absolutely accurate, after Collapse you could also add: rng.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End (Note: it's more correct to use ActiveDocument.Content than ActiveDocument.Range.)

Comment: @CindyMeister - Thanks for that info and your help on my questions! I found that `ActiveDocument.Content` note elsewhere, so have changed that.  I've added the `Collapse` and `.Content.End` as well and it seems to have worked!  After the `.Collapse` and `.Content.End`, I have also added `Set rng = Nothing`, is that okay or would that cause some issues too perhaps?

Comment: Setting the range to Nothing is correct, but not absolutely neccessary: VBA in its current incarnation is very forgiving in this regard. (In Word 97 it was not, but that got fixed in a hurry!)

Comment: I've composed the comment as an Answer. One other tip for you: try to avoid using ActiveDocument throughout your code. Declare an object (Dim doc as Word.Document for example) then set ActiveDocument to that and use doc throughout. It could happen that the user clicks on or opens another document, or some other software uses "GetObject" and picks up the same instance of the Word application. Things like that could unexpectedly change which Document is the *active* one, with nasty results...

Comment: @CindyMeister - Oh for sure, I'm doing that as we speak (I know from Excel to try and never use `ActiveSheet`, so assumed the same here.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Who would wnat to miss a chance to help Batman's rich alter ego <g>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` before the "Case 1" line.

Explanation: When you use `Find`, it executes on the given Range or Selection.

If it's successful, that Range/Selection changes to include the "found" term. In this case, you in addition change the assignment again (expanding to include the paragraph).

When your code loops the current assignment to "Range" is used - in this case, Find looks only at the selected paragraph Range. So you need to reset the Range in order to have Find continue.

To be absolutely accurate, after Collapse you could also add:

```
rng.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
```

Note: it's more correct to use `ActiveDocument.Content` than `ActiveDocument.Range`. `ActiveDocument.Range` is actually a method for creating a new Range by specifying the Start and End points, while ActiveDocument.Content returns the entire main story (body) of the document as a Range object. VBA doesn't care, it defaults the method to return the main story. Other programming languages (.NET, especially C#) don't work as intuitively with Word's object model, however. So it's a good habit to use what "always" works :-)